# How to know if the searched user is a friend already using Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

We are using Gremlin to query JanusGraph and I'm still a beginner. We have this query right now to search for users using either name, phone number or email address.

```
    g.V()
    .or(
        filter({ it.get().value("name").contains(queryStr)}),
        filter({ it.get().value("phone").contains(queryStr)}),
        filter({ it.get().value("email").contains(queryStr)}) 
    )
    .not(has('users','email',email))
    .order().by('name').valueMap()
```

This gives result like this:

```
[
  {
    phone: [ '+63123456789' ],
    displayName: [ 'User Name' ],
    name: [ 'username' ],
    email: [ 'user@example.com' ],
    picture: [ '' ]
  }
]
```

The problem with the query is that we can't identify if you're already friends with the user. I would like to add a dynamic property like isFriend, isRequestPending that would look like this if possible (if not maybe something similar will do):

```
[
  {
    phone: [ '+63123456789' ],
    displayName: [ 'User Name' ],
    name: [ 'username' ],
    email: [ 'user@example.com' ],
    picture: [ '' ],
    isFriend: [ 'true' ],
    isRequestPending: [ 'false' ]
  }
]
```

**To give more info**:
The label for the edge is called "friend". When adding a user as a friend we assign the friend edge to the user like:

```
A --friend--> B
```

If user B accepted the request then we assign the edge to user A

```
B --friend--> A
```

Thanks for those who can help.

Answer (score 2):

The `valueMap()` step is a nice convenience but is a bit like `SELECT * FROM table` in SQL which is not typically advisable to do. You can provide it specific keys to return which would be better but that still won't help you add in your additional "dynamic keys" as you refer to them. To do that, you would typically prefer `project()`:

```
g.V().or(filter({ it.get().value("name").contains(queryStr)}),
         filter({ it.get().value("phone").contains(queryStr)}),
         filter({ it.get().value("email").contains(queryStr)})).
  not(has('users','email',email)).
  order().by('name').
  project('phone','displayName','name','email','picture','isFriend','isRequestPending').
    by('phone').
    by('name').
    by('email').
    by('picture').
    by(coalesce(out('friend').has('name','B').constant(true), constant(false)).
    by(coalesce(__.in('friend').has('name','B').constant(false), constant(true))
```

As a side note, you should get rid of those lambda expressions - JanusGraph has no chance at optimizing those to use an index. You should create [appropriate indices](https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-backend/text-search/) and prefer `textContains` ([docs](https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-backend/search-predicates/)) something like:

```
g.V().or(has("name", textContains(queryStr)),
         has("phone", textContains(queryStr)),
         has("email", textContains(queryStr))).
  not(has('users','email',email)).
  order().by('name').
  project('phone','displayName','name','email','picture','isFriend','isRequestPending').
    by('phone').
    by('name').
    by('email').
    by('picture').
    by(coalesce(out('friend').has('name','B').constant(true), constant(false)).
    by(coalesce(__.in('friend').has('name','B').constant(false), constant(true))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to @stephenmallete I was able to improve my query.

```
        g.V()
        .or(
            has("name", textContainsRegex(queryStr)),
            has("phone", textContainsRegex(queryStr)),
            has("email", textContainsRegex(queryStr))
        )
        .not(has('users','email',email))
        .order().by('name')
        .project('phone','displayName','name','email','picture','relationStatus')
        .by('phone')
        .by('displayName')
        .by('name')
        .by('email')
        .by('picture')
        .by(
            union(
                coalesce(__.out('friend').has('email', email).constant(1), constant(0)),
                coalesce(__.in('friend').has('email', email).constant(1), constant(0))
            )
            .sum()
        )
```

This query results to:

```
[
  {
    phone: '+63123456789',
    displayName: 'Firstname Lastname',
    name: 'firstname lastname',
    email: 'user@example.com',
    picture: 'user.jpg',
    relationStatus: 2 // 0 = not yet friend, 1 = pending, 2 = friend already
  }
]
```

So instead of having two separate properties like isFriend and isRequestPending, I realized that I can keep it simple by making it just one property "relationStatus" with 0 as not yet friend, 1 as pending, 2 as friend. This way I can just create an enum and match the value.